# TableView with XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, tableview

I'm new to xcode, and trying to add a tableview.
for some reason, it looks that all the online guides are for older versions of xcode, and I can't find a good explanation for how to connect things.
apparently the xcode4's design is not at all as the older versions design.
can you recommend of a good guide, or maybe give me the answer?
how do I connect the view to the controller? do i need to add files? do I need a navigator?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can check out this tutorial by Matthijs Hollemans [Beginning Storyboards in iOS 5 Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

or watch the new [Stanford Itunes U Video for iOS 5 apps](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewPodcast?id=480479762).

In both they explain detailed how to use storyboard (e.g. with a `UITableView`).

Answer (score 0):

look for Stanford CSP 193 Fall 2011 on iTunesU

Comment: My link above to the iTunes U Video is the actual course which includes iOS 5 and storyboards.